# Infinite scroll image gallery in contentful / gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, contentful

As the title implies is there a resource for this? I know there is the react infinite scroll plugin, but it's connecting this to contentful / Gatsby I don't understand.

I know we can write a graphql query to get all images within an album, but how does this fit into the react plugin for infinite scroll?

There are plenty of examples with a static image gallery with a fixed number of images that just displays everything from the graphql query for an albums images. But, I just don't see anything like this.